# preg_match issues using php variable

Tags: php, regex

I have a variable I want to use in a preg_match combined with some regex:

```
$string = "cheese-123-asdf";
$find = "cheese";
if(preg_match("/$find-/d.*/", $string)) {
    echo "matched";
}
```

In my pattern I am trying to match using cheese, followed by a - and 1 digit, followed by anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. change `/d` to `\d`
2. there is no need to use `.*`
3. if your string is defined by user (or may contains some characters (e.g: `/` or `*` or `...`)) this may cause problem on your match.

Code:

```
<?php
$string = "cheese-123-asdf";
$find = "cheese";
if(preg_match("/$find-\d/", $string)) 
{
    echo "matched";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You mistyped `/` for `\`:

```
if(preg_match("/$find-\d.*/", $string)) {
```

The `.*` is also not really necessary since the pattern will match either way.

Answer (score 1):

for digit, it's `\d`

```
if(preg_match("/$find-\d.*/", $string)) {
```